# How to select items using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am selecting data from a data store [image]

I am able to fetch first array `[0] {IHSWCFService.ServiceReference1.Observation}` using below query

```
var newData = data.Select(a => new IHSData
{
    PriceSymbol = Convert.ToString(a.PriceId),
    PeriodData = Convert.ToDateTime(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.Period).FirstOrDefault()),
    StatusID = Convert.ToInt32(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.StatusId).ToList()),
    Price = Convert.ToDouble(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.price).FirstOrDefault()),
});
```

But I want to select next array also. as showing in below screen screenshot
[image]

```
[0]{IHSWCFService.ServiceReference1.Observation} 
[1]{IHSWCFService.ServiceReference1.Observation}
[2]{IHSWCFService.ServiceReference1.Observation}
```

Could you please help me. Thanks

Comment: Screenshots can't be googled or compiled. In any case, the screenshot doesn't explain anything. You already wrote a proper Select statement, assuming `data` is an IEnumerable. What is the question?

Comment: in  PeriodData = Convert.ToDateTime(a.ObservationVector.Select(x => x.Period).FirstOrDefault() I am able to read the values. but I want to read next value also.[0]{IHSWCFService.ServiceReference1.Observation}

Comment: [1] {IHSWCFService.ServiceReference1.Observation} I want to read this next value also

Comment: So every `IHSData` contains only one `PeriodData`, and in your `data` List you want to have every `Period` from the database so there will be multiple `IHSData` objects with same `PriceSymbol` but unique `PeriodData` ? And what about `Price` property ?

Comment: `Select` creates a projection which will apply to all elements in the list. If you add `.ToList()` after the `Select` method, you will get a list of the same length as the input list.

Comment: @Erexo Price symbol is only one and more than one period data is there. For example price symbol is ABC but the price in SEP month is 10 and Aug Month 11. I am able to read only 10 Not 11. Hope it helps

Comment: @Groo ToList is not working. because its datetime

Comment: `newData` is not a date time, it's an `IEnumerable<T>`. And the generic type cannot be seen because, instead of posting a [MCVE], you posted images which cover half of the code with tooltips.

Comment: @Groo There is no newList, its a newData

Comment: @Bheesham: which is not `DateTime`.

Comment: @Groo      public string PriceSymbol { get; set; }
               public DateTime PeriodData { get; set; }
             public int StatusID { get; set; }
            public double Price { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

You might want all your properties in `IHSData` to be lists:

```
var newData = data.Select(a => new IHSData
{
    PriceSymbol = Convert.ToString(a.PriceId),
    PeriodData = a.ObservationVector.Select(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Period)).ToList(),
    StatusID = a.ObservationVector.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.StatusId)).ToList(),
    Price = a.ObservationVector.Select(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.price)).ToList(),
});
```

Which is not such a good idea, because you have to index them separately. So another option would be to use `SelectMany`:

```
var newData = data
    .SelectMany(a => a.ObservationVector.Select(v =>
        new IHSData
        {
            PriceSymbol = Convert.ToString(a.PriceId),  // parent PriceId
            PeriodData = Convert.ToDateTime(v.Period),
            StatusID = Convert.ToInt32(v.StatusId),
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(v.price),
        }))
   .ToList();
```

The latter approach will create a separate `IHSData` instance for each `ObservationVector`, and some of them will share the same `PriceId` of the parent class.

Or, the third approach would be to have a new class, which would be the "parsed version of the `ObservationVector`", i.e. contain properties for parsed values, something like:

```
var newData = data.Select(a => new IHSData
{
    PriceSymbol = Convert.ToString(a.PriceId),
    Data = a.ObservationVector.Select(x => ConvertObservationVector(x)).ToList()
});
```

where `ConvertObservationVector` is a method which converts from an `ObservationVector` to your parsed class.

Comment: Thanks for reply I am just checking.

Comment: I am getting below error                                                                    Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[IHSWCFService.ServiceReference1.Observation,System.DateTime]' to type 'System.IConvertible' and using second approch

Comment: It's hard to tell without posting the code for the actual classes. It's unclear to me why you are using `Convert.ToDateTime` and `Convert.ToUInt32`, since your tooltip seems to indicate that these properties are not strings, but already have the correct type. That's why posting screenshots instead of the actual code is a bad idea.